# how to stop the install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` on the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-ec2

I'm deploying a app on production mode but when i try to finish the process the aways show this need for sqlite adapter, please someone know how to stop this issue?

i've been using RAILS_ENV=production but in this case did not worked.

```
current$ rails generate admin_interface:setup RAILS_ENV=production
DEPRECATION WARNING: Support for Rails < 4.1.0 will be dropped. (called from warn at /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/forwardable.rb:183)
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:322:in `block in replace_gem': Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` (sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (LoadError)
    from /home/ubuntu/vitrineonline/releases/10/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ubuntu/vitrineonline/releases/10/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/backports-3.6.8/lib/backports/std_lib.rb:9:in `require'
    from /home/ubuntu/vitrineonline/releases/10/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/backports-3.6.8/lib/backports/std_lib.rb:9:in `require_with_backports'
    from /home/ubuntu/vitrineonline/releases/10/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /home/ubuntu/vitrineonline/releases/10/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/ubuntu/vitrineonline/releases/10/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /home/ubuntu/vitrineonline/releases/10/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:50:in `resolve_hash_connection'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue I see is that you should put the `RAILS_ENV` declaration at the beginning of your command as this sets that variable for the life of the command.

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails generate admin_interface:setup
```

This could be the root cause entirely. (Also note the use of `bundle exec` to be sure that the gemset specified in the Gemfile is properly loaded)

If you want to set it for the shell, run:

```
export RAILS_ENV=production
```

So you don't have to manually set it for every command.

The second possibility is that the database adapter is not properly configured. If this is a Ruby on Rails app, the database adapter is defined in `config/database.yml`.  If not specified, it may be defaulting to sqlite3.  Make sure you have a properly setup database.yml file.

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: rails4_stack
  username: myusername
  password: mypassword
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
```